# Insert all records bar those in a banned list

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert

I have before insert trigger on table1. If some data (ID) is not allowed an application error is raised.

But, when I use, for example, `insert into table1 select id from table2 where id in (1,2,3)` And if only ID '3' is not allowed, the others ID's (1 and 2) are not inserted as well.

How can I overcome this? The trigger code is similar to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t1_before_insert BEFORE INSERT 
ON table1 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
xx number(20); 
BEGIN 
select id into xx from blocked_id where id=:new.id; 
if :new.id=xx then raise_application_error(-20001, '--'); 
end if; 
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, two points. Firstly, you're risking a [NO_DATA_FOUND](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS00703) exception with your SELECT INTO ..., raising this exception will kill your entire insert. Secondly you're raising an exception, which will stop your entire insert.

You need to *ignore* those IDs that are in your blocked table rather than raise an exception. To follow your original idea one method would be to utilise the NO_DATA_FOUND exception to only insert if nothing is found. I create a view on your table and define an [INSTEAD OF trigger](http://psoug.org/reference/instead_of_trigger.html) on this.

I would not use this method though (see below)

If we set-up a test-environment:

```
SQL> create table tmp_test ( id number );

Table created.

SQL> create table tmp_blocked ( id number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into tmp_blocked values (3);

1 row created.
```

Then you can use the following:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_tmp_test as select * from tmp_test;

View created.

SQL> create or replace trigger tr_test
  2   instead of insert on v_tmp_test
  3   for each row
  4
  5  declare
  6
  7     l_id tmp_test.id%type;
  8
  9  begin
 10
 11     select id into l_id
 12       from tmp_blocked
 13      where id = :new.id;
 14
 15  exception when no_data_found then
 16     insert into tmp_test values (:new.id);
 17  end;
 18  /

Trigger created.

SQL> show error
No errors.

SQL>  insert into v_tmp_test
  2   select level
  3     from dual
  4  connect by level <= 3;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * from tmp_test;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
```

As I said, I would not use triggers; a more efficient way of doing it would be to use [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606). Using the same set-up as above.

```
SQL> merge into tmp_test o
  2  using ( select a.id
  3            from ( select level as id
  4                     from dual
  5                  connect by level <= 3 ) a
  6            left outer join tmp_blocked b
  7              on a.id = b.id
  8           where b.id is null
  9                 ) n
 10     on ( o.id = n.id )
 11   when not matched then
 12    insert values (n.id);

2 rows merged.

SQL>
SQL> select * from tmp_test;

        ID
----------
         1
         2
```

An even easier alternative would be to just use a [MINUS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries004.htm#SQLRF52341)

```
 insert into tmp_test
 select level
   from dual
connect by level <= 3
  minus
 select id
   from tmp_banned
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't like the use of a trigger and an error in this way -- data integrity is not really what triggers are for. This seems to me to be a part of the application that should be included in the application code, perhaps in a procedure that acts as an API for inserts into the table.